# How to return back data through GET from flask route to jquery and load it in dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, postgresql, flask

```
@app.route('/loadsubcat', methods =\['GET'\])
def loadsubcat():
  sub_cat = request.args.get('category_id')
  sub_cat_data = subcategories.query.filter(subcategories.categoryID == sub_cat).all()
  sub_data = "example"
  return jsonify({"hello": sub_cat_data})
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
    var cat_id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/loadsubcat",
      data: { category_id: cat_id },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(sub_cat_data){
        alert(sub_cat_data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
          console.log(data[i].subcategory_name);
        }
        $("#sub_cat").empty();
        var output = "";
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(a,b){
          // console.log(data);
          output += "<option value='"+b.id+"'>"+b.subcategory_name+"  </option>"
          $("#sub_cat").append(output);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I am trying to send first dropdown value to route then fetch results and based on that first dropdown value i am passing i am trying to load my second dependent dropdown.

I am stuck how to send data back through get api which is fetched through database.

Comment: your code seems ok, what is the error you are facing or what is happing in your code ? please share the `<select` tag html also

Comment: <div class="form-group ">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="    color: #525252;"> sub catagory 
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
    </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `jsonify` does not directly convert a object to json therefore we need to write an encoder

you can use [marshmallow](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Otherwise I found an [encoder code](https://gist.github.com/frfernandezdev/f86c7b5a8f4154a5a454347d630be510) to make your code as it is

download the code and save as `json_serializable.py`, then import use the encoder as below, then your code will work

```
from json_serializable import JSONSerializable

db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)
JSONSerializable(app)
```

Fine tune you javascript code as below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#parent_cat").change(
            function() {
                var cat_id = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : "/loadsubcat",
                    data : {
                        category_id : cat_id
                    },
                    contentType : 'application/json',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $("#sub_cat").empty();
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                            output = "<option value='"+data[i].id+"'>"
                            + data[i].subcategory_name + "  </option>"
                            $("#sub_cat").append(output);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
      });
```

Comment: TypeError: Object of type subcategories is not JSON serializable

Comment: @app.route('/loadsubcat', methods =['GET'])
def loadsubcat():
    sub_cat = request.args.get('category_id')
    sub_cat_data = subcategories.query.filter(subcategories.categoryID == sub_cat).all()
    sub_data = "example"
    return str(sub_cat_data)


when i printing results using str(sub_cat_data) I am able to fetch results but how to send same results to javascript using resturn jsonify?

Comment: from javascript you are already sending to server `$("#parent_cat").change(function() {
var cat_id = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "/loadsubcat",
data: { category_id: cat_id },`

Comment: from server you are already receiving as `success: function(sub_cat_data){
alert(sub_cat_data);`

Comment: you are doing both, but you are asking how, after doing it ? what is the actual issue you are facing ?

Comment: TypeError: Object of type subcategories is not JSON serializable

The data is not loaded in javascript

Comment: @app.route('/loadsubcat', methods =['GET'])
def loadsubcat():
    sub_cat = request.args.get('category_id')
    sub_cat_data = subcategories.query.filter(subcategories.categoryID == sub_cat).all()
    sub_data = "example"
    return jsonify({"hello": sub_cat_data})

Comment: $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        var cat_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "/loadsubcat",
   data: { category_id: cat_id },
   contentType: 'application/json',
   dataType: 'json',
            success: function(sub_cat_data){
    alert(sub_cat_data);
    var data = sub_cat_data.hello
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                    console.log(data[i].subcategory_name);
                }
            }
        });
    });

Comment: `TypeError: Object of type subcategories is not JSON serializable The data is not loaded in javascript` this is your actual issue, put it in your question please

Comment: what is `subcategories.query.filter` mongodb ? or mysql ? postgresql ?

Comment: subcategories.query.filter is postgresql

Comment: writing code for you, will share in few hours

Comment: will be waiting

Comment: jsonify is the problem, you can try `marshmellow` --- https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/